# ios multiple class implementation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, oop, class

I came from front-end development, so MVC and OOP still give me some head shakes. Just to explain to you I send like 500 dicionaries (with 100 parameters) to a nodejs server. The problem is that I has creating ivars for each parameter and each dicionary. Now I want to create some classes like a person class, in the same header file that I have my syncronization class for example. I can make something like this on the header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GCDAsyncSocket.h"

@class GCDAsyncSocket;

@interface socketDelegate : NSObject<NSStreamDelegate>
{
    NSInputStream   *inputStream;
    NSOutputStream  *outputStream;
    NSMutableArray  *messages;
    GCDAsyncSocket *socket;
    dispatch_queue_t connectionQueue_;
}

- (void) initNetworkCommunication;
- (void) sendMessage:(NSArray *)message:(int)numberOfContactsToSend;

@end

@interface  personInfo: NSObject

@property (nonatomic,weak)NSString*firstName;
@property (nonatomic,weak)NSString*lastName;
@property (nonatomic,weak)NSDictionary*dicToSendWithConctactInfo;

@end
```

But in the implementation I don't know how to handle the multiple classes. Like I've a method inside the "socketDelegate" class that needs to use the person class, but it's not available inside it.

What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by "a method inside the "socketDelegate" class that needs to use the person class, but it's not available inside it."?

Comment: I mean that I can't implement the person class inside the socketclass, but the socket class is responsible to send the person info, but if I've not implemented the person class, I'm not hable to access it :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, you can just forward-declare `personInfo` at the top of the file before `socketDelegate`:

```
@class personInfo;
```

Usually you just put each public class in its own implementation and header files, and each implementation file includes the header files of all the classes it uses. The header files usually just need to forward declare the classes they refer to (as you are doing with `@class GCDAsyncSocket;`. However, it doesn't make sense that you are both importing `#import "GCDAsyncSocket.h"` and forward-declaring. From what you are using it for here, you don't need the import. However, to properly use `GCDAsyncSocket`, you will need to implement `GCDAsyncSocketDelegate` protocol, which will require you to import the header; however, you should probably implement that protocol as part of a "class extension" inside the implementation file).

You only need to import the header of something in your header if you are subclassing a class, or implementing a protocol that is declared in the header. For all other uses (i.e. using the class or protocol as part of a pointer type), you can simply forward-declare it. (And for implementing a protocol, you can do that in the implementation file with a "class extension" if you don't need people to know you're implementing the protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Different classes should, typically, be in different files.  Once `PersonInfo` (please capitalize class names) has it's own `PersonInfo.h` and `PersonInfo.m`, then you simply add

```
#import "PersonInfo.h"
```

to the header file above to be able to reference `PersonInfo` from your `SocketDelegate` class (again, please capitalize class names).

Comment: It makes sense. And I will need it on more than one class. And thanks also for the class capitalization tip!

Comment: When I use it on other class, I don't need to syntetize ir do I?

Comment: And another question, when I've have to call this person class 500 times, or more. Do I have to init and alloc it everytime?

Comment: Properties need to be synthesized, no matter what type the property is.  If you want 500 instances of `PersonInfo`, then you need to instantiate `PersonInfo` 500 times (which means `[[PersonInfo alloc] init]`. This, obviously, would best be done with some kind of loop.

Comment: Ok, And the release of that PersonInfo is made automatically?

Comment: Don't confuse properties with instantiating a class.  A property it's own thing. If you have questions about properties and memory management, then post a new question.

Comment: No, he doesn't need to include the header at all here. He is just using the type of the pointer to this class. A forward declaration is sufficient. Including headers in headers should be avoided as much as possible because they can lead to circular dependency and other problems.